# how to add more items with the GroupDescriptors of the header of RadJumpList in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

how to add more items with the GroupDescriptors of the header of RadJumpList in wp7?By default we are getting the GroupDescriptors as a Header, I need to add one more property ,which is including in the same itemsource.

Comment: Are you talking about Telerik RadJumpList? And for your question, what do you want to do with the additional property that relates to the GroupDescriptors?

Comment: I am using Telerik RadJumpList.I just need to display that property with the descriptor as a header.